# Integer will call to one class, but not to another?

Tags: java, graphics, integer, coordinates

I'm trying to make the game "Snake," but I'm getting stuck on the tail. Right 
now, I'm just trying to make the first tail block have the same coordinates as the
head. Here's what I have. For the main class:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
Snake p;
RandomDot r;
Trail trail; 
Point w;
Image img;
Timer time;
int t=75;
int score = 0;
int count = 0;
int x, y;


boolean lost = false;

public Game(){
    p = new Snake();
    r = new RandomDot();
    trail = new Trail();
    w = new Point();
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setFocusable(true);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Matt's stuff/background.png");
    img = i.getImage();
    time = new Timer(t, this);
    time.start();
} 

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    p.move();
    p.moveup();
    w.points();
    trail.getFirstDot();
    trail.findCoords();
    if (score>=1)
    {
    trail.getFirstDot();
    }
    if (lost==true)
    {
        score++;
        r.getRandom();
        lost = false;
    }
    repaint();
    checkCollisions();
}


public int score()
{
    return score;
}

public boolean getLost()
{
    return lost;
}

public void checkCollisions()
{
    Rectangle r1 = r.getBounds();
    Rectangle r2 = p.getBounds();
    if (r1.intersects(r2))
    {
        lost = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
        super.paint(g);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                    g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
                    g2d.drawImage(r.getImage2(), r.getX2(), r.getY2(), null);
                    if (score>=1)
                    {
                        g2d.drawImage(trail.getImage(), trail.getX(), trail.getY(),       null);
                    }
                    System.out.println(score + "00");
}

private class AL extends KeyAdapter{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        p.keyReleased(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        p.keyPressed(e);
    }
}

}
```

For the Snake's head's class:

```
public class Snake {
Integer x = 480, y = 280, dx = 0, dy = 0, h, m;
boolean dead = false;
boolean didmove = false;
Image still;
RandomDot r;
Game g;
Trail t;

public Snake(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Matt's Stuff/snake.png");
    still = i.getImage();
}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y, 10, 10);
} 


public void move(){ 
    x = x + dx;
    h = x;
    didmove = true;
    if (x>=990||x<=5){
    dead = true;
    x = 480;
    y = 280;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    didmove = false;
    }
} 

public void moveup(){
    y = y + dy;
    m = y;
    didmove = true;
    if (y>=590||y<=0){
    dead = true;
    x = 480;
    y = 280;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    didmove = false;
    }
}

public Integer getX(){
return x;
}

public Integer getY(){
return y;
}

public Image getImage(){
return still;
}
public boolean getBoolean(){
return dead;
}

public boolean didmove(){
return didmove;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
int key = e.getKeyCode();

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
     if (dead == false){
        dx = -10;
        dy = 0;
    } else {
        x = 480;
        y = 280;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
    }
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
    if (dead == false){
        dx = 10;
        dy = 0;
    } else {
        x = 480;
        y = 280;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
    }
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
    if (dead == false){
        dy = -10;
        dx = 0;
    }else {
        x = 480;
        y = 280;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
    }
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
    if (dead == false){
        dy = 10;
        dx = 0;
    }else {
        x = 480;
        y = 280;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
    }
}
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
int key = e.getKeyCode();



}

}
```

And lastly, the tail:

```
public class Trail {
Image still;
Integer x = 500, y = 500, dx, dy, dx2, dy2;
Game g;
Snake p;
Point d;
int count=0;


boolean visible = false;
public Trail(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Matt's Stuff/Dot.png");
    still = i.getImage();
    p = new Snake();
    d = new Point();
}

public void getFirstDot(){
    visible = true;
}

public void findCoords(){
    if (visible == true)
    { 
        x = p.getX();
        y = p.getY();
    }
}

public Integer getX(){
    return x;
}

public Integer getY(){
    return y;
}

public Image getImage(){
    return still;
}
}
```

Now my problem is this: The `p.getX()` and `p.getY()` in the tail class do not work! The tail block just sits there where the snake's head initially started! I don't know what is going on, none of my research seems to help! Please help me out? Why is it that `p.getX()` and `p.getY()` will work in the main Game class, but not the Tail's? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider using a debugger or peppering your code with debug statements to see why it's behaving the way its behaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `new Snake()` inside your `Trail` constructor, and then referring to *that* `Snake` instead of the one the `Game` knows about. Instead of creating a *new* `Snake`, you should pass in a reference to the constructor, so that you call the methods of the object that is actually being updated:

```
// In the Trail class
public Trail(Snake s) {
    p = s;
    // other stuff
}

// In the Game class:
trail = new Trail(p);
// ...
```

Now when you call `p.getX()` and so on, you'll actually be pointing at the correct `Snake`, so you should see your position update correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That makes sense, and it solved my "null" problem as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the reference of existing `Snake` object to `Trail` constructor to make it work. For example in `Game` class your code should be like this:

```
public Game(){
    p = new Snake();
    r = new RandomDot();
    trail = new Trail(p);//Pass the reference of Snake so that you get all information w.r.t the current Snake in consideration
    w = new Point();
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setFocusable(true);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Matt's stuff/background.png");
    img = i.getImage();
    time = new Timer(t, this);
    time.start();
}
```

And change the Trail constructor as follows:

```
public Trail(Snake p){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Matt's Stuff/Dot.png");
    still = i.getImage();
    this.p = p;
    d = new Point();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, and thank you, but now it says that the `p.getX()` in the Trail class is null? (NullPointerException)